# Presentation component is getting cached while moving between screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am building a react-native app, in which all screens share the same generic functionality like
    1. Making ajax requests
    2. convert snake_case keys to camelCase
    3. show loading indicator while fetching data
    4. subscribe to redux store and expose store as props

here are the tools I am using

1. react-native
2. expo
3. redux
4. react-redux
5. react-navigation

My container has no idea what urls to fetch because it is used with all the components. I am calling the container component in this way

```
const fetchUrls = store => return [url, url];
return MycontainerComponent(WrapperComponent)(fetchUrls);
```

this seems to work fine on initial load, but didn't work when visiting a screen, navigate to another and come back to the first screen again. Its as if components are cached and not recomputed again. this is for me as long as no data in the store changed. so I wrote a watcher inside the container component and to see if any value in the store changes, the component will re-render. but then this worked fine until I had one more problem.

I want to support user switch like in gmail because mine is a parent app and a parent can have 2 or more children studying at the same school and u can understand the rest.

Now when I am switching the user, I updated the redux store and I thought it would re-render stuff and it would be all fine. Until I hit with reality.

When I switch user, it seems as if the component is trying to unmount and fetch urls for new store values at the same time and react complaints with typical "don't setstate in the componentwillunmount, its a no-op, unsubscribe etc."

I have no idea what's happening, can anyone shed some light on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With a stack Navigator the screens are not unmounted after they lose focus. This is a performance optimization. If you want to execute logic when a screen regains focus put your logic in [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) onWillFocus or onDidFocus.

Comment: Excellent, will try that out.